# If I delete from my drive - will it delete on another person's drive that I've uploaded to?

Tags: google-drive

Sorry if this is a bit convoluted. My client has shared all their Google Drive folders with me. I do the work, and then upload into the respective folders. For some reason - the work I've done ends up on my drive too. No clue why. (If anyone can answer that, that'll be a bonus!)

If I delete the work from my drive, to free up space - will they delete on my client's side too?

Comment: Yes, you own the items, so if you delete them, they are deleted for everybody.

Answer (score 2):

If your client has a Google Workspace (formerly G Suite) Business or higher account, ask them to create a Shared Drive (formerly Team Drive) then move the files you uploaded there.

The above because if you upload the files to a folder that is in "My Drive", no matter if your client is the folder owner, the files consume your Google storage quota, and if you delete them, then your client will not be able to open them.

Related

- [How can I delete a shared file from Google Drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/55274/88163)
- [What happens to files when deleted from a shared folder which has been added to their Google Drive?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/137036/88163)
- [If I delete a file from my "shared with me" files, is it deleted for anyone else that file may have been shared with as well?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/141379/88163)